# How can I reference data of DataGridView into SQL database in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am new to database and C#. I am building an EPOS software and I just want to 
reference the data which is in DataGridView into SQL database (if I am saying it correct).
Ok, here is what I am trying to do:

as shown in the photo, I have customer1 order details (3 rows) in DataGridView and this details is only for one customer1. Now when I finish with customer1, its order details is saved in database. Next, when I finish with customer2 order, its details is saved in database. Next, customer3 order details will be saved in database.... and so on.

Now for example at some point in the future I want to read back / Edit (or check) 
 customer2 order details from database and populate it into DataGridView.

I have been thinking how to do it but I failed and I am confused. 
Can you please provide me with an idea or code in how to check what did Customer2 order. thank you.

[image: photo]

Comment: What you have in the DataGridView is a DataTable, the DataGridView is simply a control used to provide you with visualization and some functionality. In order to alter the information in the database you need to open database connection and send a query.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Customer` Model which represent your table. Then create a method which will return a collection. I'm going to assume you've got your connection string setup and know how to read it in your code using c#. So the code could look like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}

public List<Customer> GetCustomerData()
{
  var list = new List<Customer>();

  string sqlQuery = "SELECT Qty, Des, Price From MyTable Where Customer = SomeCustomer"; //Change accordingly
  string connectionString = "Your Connection String";

  using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
    {
      connection.Open();

       using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
         while (reader.Read())
         {
            var c = new Customer();
            c.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Qty"]);
            c.Description = reader["Des"].ToString();
            c.Price = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Price"]);

            list.Add(c);
          }
       }
     }
   }
   return list;
}
```

Finnaly to display the data on the `DataGrid` you'll do:

```
MyGrid.ItemsSource = GetCustomerData(); //Change MyGrid to whatever you've named your grid
```

Please note: I haven't tested the above code so it might require some small changes. However it should give you a good idea.

Comment: Hi Izzy. based on your code, how do you identify each row in the database to which customer belongs to? I mean how do you identify customer2' rows in the database? (how do you know which row in the database belongs to which customer?)

Comment: @naouf Well that depends on the database structure, You'll have to make it unique i.e by adding `PK` to the desired table. I suggest you read into databases a little more. Once you've got it setup correctly you can filter it in your `Where` clause which will give you result for each customer